# How to do this select join in Zend_Db_Select?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

How do I make this in Zend_Db_Select?

I have this query and I need make in Zend:

```
SELECT

  `cursos_categorias`.`rotulo` AS `categoria`,
  `cursos`.`titulo`,
  `cursos`.`subTitulo`,
  `imagens`.`src` AS `imagem`,
  `cursos`.`url`,
  `cursos`.`destacado`

   FROM `suprema_db`.`cursos`

   JOIN `cursos_categorias` ON `cursos`.`categoriaId` = `cursos_categorias`.`id`
   JOIN `imagens` ON `cursos`.`imagemId` = `imagens`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$select->from(array('c' => 'cursos'), array('titulo', 'subTitulo'))
             ->join(array('cc'=> 'cursos_categorias'), 'c.categoriaId = cc.id', array('categoria' => 'cc.rotulo'))
             ->join(array('i' => 'imagens'), 'c.imagemId = i.id', array('imagem' => 'i.src'));
```